# Did Albert Einstein really say he wished he would have "studied the Talmud?"

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, albert-einstein

In Rabbi Aaron Parry's "[The Complete Idiot's Guide to The Talmud](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592572022),"   Rabbi Parry writes in the introduction:

[image]

Is this a true statement, and if so is there a **legitimate** source where this statement can be attributed to?   (ie biography, close family member, etc)

Comment: Sounds dubious, considering Einstein's nearly completely non-religious upbringing.

Comment: perhaps migrate this to history or some other SE

Comment: @drshmuel how is this question not on topic?

Comment: @ezra as a youth, he actually was observant for a time (see #1) https://www.aish.com/ci/s/10-Little-Known-Facts-about-Einstein.html

Comment: @alicht How is it on-topic? It’s a question about a Jew, not about Judaism.

Comment: @DonielF doing a search of "did really say" shows a number of similar questions, all of which aren't closed

Comment: @alicht All of the ones I see are questions about Biblical personalities, or questions about Halacha, both of which are on-topic. I don’t see how a question about if someone learned Gemara is necessarily on-topic.

Comment: @donielf it's asking about verifying whether a statement is true, but I understand and do see the *chiluk*

Comment: I suspect this could be migrated to skeptics.se

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic, @DoubleAA. It's about Talmud study by a Jew.

Comment: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/52807/6962

Answer (score 2):

No, he did not. Almost 10 years ago I was sitting at a Chabad lunch when one of the custodians of the Albert Einstein Archive at Hebrew University gave a speech. Someone asked him if it was true Einstein died religious by saying shema' (another tale of his religiosity). He said that Einstein never said or did anything in [old age] that we [faithful Jews] would consider religious.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would be great if there was hard link/source that one could point to

Comment: @Aaron, you are mistaken. Einstein, for a time, was a religious, observant Jew.

Comment: @TurkHill On what do you base this on? According to Einstein himself he wasn't an "observant Jew," and abandoned any notions about a personal God by the age of 12. ". . I came—though the child of entirely irreligious (Jewish) parents—to a deep religiousness, which, however, reached an abrupt end at the age of twelve. Through the reading of popular scientific books I soon reached the conviction that much in the stories of the Bible could not be true...."

Comment: @Aaron I was referring to his youth before he reached the age of 12.

Comment: @TurkHill And your evidence that he was "observant" despite going to a Catholic school that he was sent to by his irreligious parents?

Comment: @Aaron I read that he was Observant. That is to say, that he kept kosher, the mitzvahs, and studied Talmud and Torah. I will get back to you on the sources regarding this.

Comment: @Aaron Albert attended a local Munich Catholic elementary school until about the age of 12. This was due to when a Jewish medical student ironically named, Max Talmud (later Dr. Max Talmey) gave him popular science books during his parent's dinner. Though he was never barred mitzvah, he would help students do their "religion homework." About the age of nine, he began keeping kosher, observing Shabbat and praying on his way to school. He had, at that time, developed a real love for Judaism.

Comment: @Aaron He came to believe in a “pantheistic” god, that of Spinoza, a Dutch rationalist, excommunicated from the Amsterdam Jewish community. He did not believe in an anthropomorphic G-d. He wrote to a rabbi in 1929, I believe in Spinoza’s God who reveals himself in the harmony of all being, not in a God who concerns himself with the fate and actions of men.”

Comment: I find it hard to believe that "Einstein never said or did anything that we (faithful Jews) would consider religious" is to be taken literally. He never honored his parents? He never refrained from striking someone when tempted? Surely that's not what the archive custodian meant. And expressing a vain wish that he had previously studied Talmud is not more religious than those, so the custodian's claim doesn't include that either.

Comment: @TurkHill What source are you quoting from?

Comment: @Aaron at this point I no longer  remember, but the idea is certainly there. I’m sure, if you google it, you’ll find it that it is sourced somewhere.

Comment: @TurkHill A lot of Jewish websites have this reference about his religiosity, but there aren't really any details. We don't know how long it lasted, or what Einstein meant by "Keeping Kosher" when his parents were very unreligious. And to have his religiosity end before or at 12 means he couldn't have been observant of very much.

Comment: @Aaron he probably didn’t keep kosher very long. Nonetheless, he would had been keeping Shabbat at one point.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The statement is true. Although Albert Einstein was agnostic, he was a Zionist and supported the secular government of Israel. He was a scientist, physicist, and philosopher. So when you hear the famous quote, “science without religion is lame and religion without science is blind,” he was referring to religion as a metaphor for the universe. Not religion in and of itself. We will get to his thoughts on religion in a moment. The same approach can be applied to another quote, “G-d does not play dice with the universe.”

In his “G-d letter”, he relates the following thoughts, “The word G-d is for me nothing more than the expression and product of human weakness, the Bible a collection of honorable, but still purely primitive, legends which are nevertheless pretty childish. No interpretation, no matter how subtle, can change this for me. For me the Jewish religion like all other religions is an incarnation of the most childish superstition.“

...I don’t think he had any motivation to study Talmud for religious reasons. However, he did write later to Talmudic scholar, Prof. Chaim Tchernowitz that the Talmud must be preserved and not forgotten amongst the Jewish community nor the scientific community. And he wished to make the Talmud more assessable for the masses in order to avoid attacks against the Talmud and anti-Semitism.

Another source is from the Michael Enright’s program, The Sunday Edition. There, a scholarly interview claimed that on Einstein’s deathbed he was asked, “if you could do it all over, what would you do differently?” Supposedly the greatest scientist ever to live answered “I would study more Talmud.”

See link here: https://relaxandsucceed.com/2013/12/27/most-popular-blog-of-the-year-countdown-3/

Comment: This is interesting background but does not answer the question which was regarding a specific quote. Do you have information on this?

Comment: @mbloch Not exactly. Although the answer serves as an alternative source for why Einstein might have made that quote.

Comment: @mbloch As far as I know, the only other time I heard the quote outside of Rabbi Aaron Parry's book is the Michael Enright’s program, The Sunday Edition.

There, a scholarly interview claimed that on Einstein’s deathbed he was asked, “if you could do it all over, what would you do differently?” Supposedly the greatest scientist ever to live answered “I would study more Talmud.”

Comment: Your last comment is confirmed by a blogpost [here](https://relaxandsucceed.com/2013/12/27/most-popular-blog-of-the-year-countdown-3/) - I would suggest to include this in your answer as it would then answer more directly (and you'd get my upvote :->)

Comment: That blogpost later says "Personally if I were a betting man I’d bet he didn’t say it, but both things are possible and in the end I really don’t care either way. I would throw whatever fiction I needed in a post to get a lesson across anyway." Not sure what to make of that

Comment: @Silver I think the person doesn’t want to anger all the atheists in the room. Regardless, even if he said it, I don’t think Einstein was a religious man, although he did keep kosher in his youth. I think Einstein saw the importance of Talmudic study and realized its potential in Jewish thought & philosophy. He was a philosopher. Refer to my answer above.

Comment: What Einstein told Tchernowitz: “The scientific organization and comprehensive exposition in accessible form of the Talmud has a twofold importance for us Jews. It is important in the first place that the high cultural values of the Talmud should not be lost to modern minds among the Jewish people, nor to science, but should operate further as a living force. In the second place, the Talmud must be made an open book to the world, in order to cut the ground from under certain malevolent attacks which borrow countenance from the obscurity and inaccessibility of certain passages in the Talmud.”

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Yes. That is what he wrote. Thank you. :)